# Why does react show previous value onclick,

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have 3 array of objects that i am trying to console log.
Whenever the array is changed(via a button click from a separate component) I simply want to log the array of objects associated with the clicked button.

But there's some delayed reaction going on

EXAMPLE:

- Arr1 - 3objs -> associated with btn1
- Arr2 - 6objs -> associated with btn2
- Arr3 - 2objs -> associated with btn3

WHAT I AM EXPECTING:

- when I click btn1 display array of 3objs
- when I click btn2 display array 6objs
- when I click btn3 display array 2objs

HOW IT IS ACTUALLY PERFORMING:

- click btn1 -> [ ]
- click btn2 -> display array of 3objs
- click btn3 -> display array 6objs
- click btn1 -> display array 2objs
- click btn2 -> display array of 3objs

its always 1 behind what it should be.

CODE:

```
  // These variables are being passed in as props ->  
getKpiResolvedTix, 
getKpiCanceledTix,
getKpiClosedTix

const [newKpiTixArr, setNewKpiTixArr] = useState<any>([])

  const renderCsvData = () => {
    if (getKpiResolvedTix) {
      setNewKpiTixArr(getKpiResolvedTix)
    } else if (getKpiCanceledTix) {
      setNewKpiTixArr(getKpiCanceledTix)
    } else if (getKpiClosedTix) {
      setNewKpiTixArr(getKpiClosedTix)
    }
}

  useEffect(() => {
    renderCsvData()
    console.log(newKpiTixArr)
  }, [getKpiResolvedTix, getKpiCanceledTix, getKpiClosedTix])
```

CODE EXPLANATION:

```
//each of the 3 "get" variables are props. essentially
when a button is clicked the tickets are filtered
to show only those tickets. 

//essentially if you click the resolve button -> it will
display all tickets with a resolved status. behind
the scenes this is an array of ticket objects.
  getKpiResolvedTix,
  getKpiCanceledTix,
  getKpiClosedTix
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because useEffect is running your console.log() before updating the state which is newKpiTixArr.

to fix that you either place your console.log(newKpiTixArr) outside of a useEffect this way it will be logged each time the component re-renders. or if you want to log it only when it changes then add another useEffect that listens to changes only on newKpiTixArr state and place your console.log() inside it. like this below

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log(newKpiTixArr)
}, [newKpiTixArr])
```

Answer (score 1):

The state change is effective only at the next rendering.

Please take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54069332/11197189) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

try spreading the arrays when set state as showed bellow

```html
const renderCsvData = () => {
    if (getKpiResolvedTix) {
      setNewKpiTixArr([...getKpiResolvedTix])
    } else if (getKpiCanceledTix) {
      setNewKpiTixArr([...getKpiCanceledTix])
    } else if (getKpiClosedTix) {
      setNewKpiTixArr([...getKpiClosedTix])
    }
}
```